# How to figure out in which projects a certain dll is used

Tags: .net, dll, dependencies

One of our other teams was upgrading a dll to .NET 4.0 which broke a lot of existing projects that where not migrated yet (.NET 3.5). The problem is that we can not figure out where the dependency on this dll comes from. 
When Visual Studio builds the affected project it copies this dll to the bin folder.
I have manually stepped through all references of references of references in ILSpy yet came out empty handed.

I'd like to know a way to build a dependency tree I can search, so I can see where this dll is being used.

Comment: Have you tried enabling assembly binding logging?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in the GAC ?

(C:\Windows\assembly)

You can check in .csproj files, you have every data about reference :)

Comment: I'm talking about a .net assembly that is not in the GAC. It is probably a dependency of a dependency of a dependency of a .... But I can't find it anywhere. As I said I have run through all of them using ILSpy. Well probably not all of them obviously.